# problem in rospack find my package

Tags: ros, path, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Indigo version of ROS. I just tried to create a package by reading ros tutorial. I am using rosbuild tool for creating. but i got a problem when executing this command "rospack find ". i am new in ROS, please tried to elaborate more. my terminal output as follow:

```
root@CHHONKAR:/home/chhonkar/Desktop# roscreate-pkg mypack std_msgs rospy roscpp
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
WARNING: current working directory is not on ROS_PACKAGE_PATH!
Please update your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Created package directory /home/chhonkar/Desktop/mypack
Created include directory /home/chhonkar/Desktop/mypack/include/mypack
Created cpp source directory /home/chhonkar/Desktop/mypack/src
Created package file /home/chhonkar/Desktop/mypack/Makefile
Created package file /home/chhonkar/Desktop/mypack/manifest.xml
Created package file /home/chhonkar/Desktop/mypack/CMakeLists.txt
Created package file /home/chhonkar/Desktop/mypack/mainpage.dox

Please edit mypack/manifest.xml and mainpage.dox to finish creating your package
root@CHHONKAR:/home/chhonkar/Desktop# rospack profile 
Full tree crawl took 0.018203 seconds.
Directories marked with (*) contain no manifest.  You may
want to delete these directories.
To get just of list of directories without manifests,
re-run the profile with --zombie-only
-------------------------------------------------------------
0.017421   /opt/ros/indigo/share
0.000042 * /opt/ros/indigo/share/man
0.000030 * /opt/ros/indigo/share/doc
0.000007 * /opt/ros/indigo/share/man/man1
0.000005 * /opt/ros/indigo/share/doc/liborocos-kdl
root@CHHONKAR:/home/chhonkar/Desktop# rospack find mypack
[rospack] Error: package 'mypack' not found
```

please tell me how to update ROS PATH. I already seen the ROS PACKAGE PATH but syntax is not clear to me...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196059/problem-in-rospack-find-my-package../) by [ASHISH CHHONKAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20131/ashish-chhonkar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can add a package directory to your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH using the `export` command in your shell:

export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:/home/chhonkar/Desktop/mypack"

This sets ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to the previous ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, and appends the path seraparator (a colon `:`) and the path to your new package.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ASHISH CHHONKAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20131/ashish-chhonkar/) on 2014-10-30**:
thanks for your reply...... this sort out my problem successfully.